# Algorithm problem solving: How to simplify the following javascript code?

Tags: javascript

## Function description

when const mergeTable=[2],
Expected function return value

```
{ rowSpan: 2 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
```

when const mergeTable=[2,3];
Expected function return value

```
{ rowSpan: 2 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
{ rowSpan: 3 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
```

when const mergeTable=[2,3,3,2]; Expected function return value

```
{ rowSpan: 2 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
{ rowSpan: 3 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
{ rowSpan: 3 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
{ rowSpan: 2 }
{ rowSpan: 0 }
```

functions that need to be optimized,
The function has been implemented, the code is redundant, how to optimize

```
const mergeTable = [2, 3, 3, 2]; // test ok

// How to simplify this function
function renderRowSpan(index) {
  for (let i in mergeTable) {
    i = Number(i);
    if (i === 0) {
      if (index === 0) {
        return { rowSpan: mergeTable[0] };
      } else if (index < mergeTable[0]) {
        return { rowSpan: 0 };
      }
    }

    if (i === 1) {
      if (index === mergeTable[0]) {
        return { rowSpan: mergeTable[1] };
      }
      if (index < mergeTable[0] + mergeTable[1]) {
        return { rowSpan: 0 };
      }
    }

    if (i === 2) {
      if (index === mergeTable[0] + mergeTable[1]) {
        return { rowSpan: mergeTable[2] };
      }
      if (index < mergeTable[0] + mergeTable[1] + mergeTable[2]) {
        return { rowSpan: 0 };
      }
    }

    if (i === 3) {
      if (index === mergeTable[0] + mergeTable[1] + mergeTable[2]) {
        return { rowSpan: mergeTable[3] };
      }
      if (
        index < (mergeTable[0] + mergeTable[1] + mergeTable[2] + mergeTable[3])
      ) {
        return { rowSpan: 0 };
      }
    }
  }
}

// execute function
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  console.log(renderRowSpan(index));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work and produce dynamic result as per number of elements in mergeTable.

```
function renderRowSpan(mergeTable){
    const result = [];
    for (const item of mergeTable) {
        let i = item;
        while(i > 0) {
            result.push({ rowSpan: i === item ? item : 0 });
            i--;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderRowSpan(mergeTable){ 
    return mergeTable.reduce(function(o, n){
       o.push({rowspan:n}); 
       for(let i=1; i<n; ++i) o.push({rowspan:0}); 
       return o;
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.